# Facebook Webhook Feed not receiving data from live page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on this stupid app for a week and can not for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong.

I have created the app, Added Webhooks and connected the webhooks to my site.  I created a log file to log all incoming connections and nothing is coming in.  I can test it using the developer system and it works perfectly but nothing I do will get it work on the live page.

Basic Test Code

```
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge']) && $verify_token == '08231984'){
   echo $challenge;
}
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $content);
```

Advanced Access Permissions: pages_show_list, public_profile, pages_manage_metadata, email

I am use to seeing a status switch in the address bar that has developer mode and live.  This switch is not displayed in the address bar anymore and I have checked in multiple browsers.

I have business verified, business account manager setup and the page is added that I wish to monitor as well as myself as a user.

I am at a complete loss on how to get this thing working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it solved? I did test it using the developer system and it works perfectly but nothing I did not get it work on the live page.

Comment: any update on it ? I am still struggling with live I can get data on test but on live?

Comment: I gave up on the project.  No one could figure it out.